# Exceptions vs special cases

Tags: word-difference

What is the difference between *exceptions* and *special cases*?

[Example](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-864-advanced-natural-language-processing-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lec01.pdf):

> Determiner placement is largely determined by [X, Y and Z], however many exceptions and special cases play a role.

Comment: I don't think there *is* a meaningful difference - using both is probably redundant.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus Thanks. You are welcome to convert your comment into an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *are* sometimes differences between the two words. One example is in technical jargon - a 'special case' [is a legal term](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/special+case), for instance, and in programming, an 'exception' can refer to [specific error-handling concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling).

*However*, as used in the quote, 'exception' and 'special case' are synonymous - both describe an unusual circumstance in which some more general rule does not apply. Mentioning both in this case is probably redundant.